# How to kill command prompt in Typescript

Tags: typescript, cmd, command-prompt

I need to completely close the cmd where the typescript file is running but I can't do that.

How can I do that?

```
console.log('This ts file must be terminate itself');

let asdef = process.pid;
let asdeff = process.ppid;

const {exec} = require('child_process')

// Kills a PID and all child process
exec(`Taskkill /PID ${asdef} /T`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
    throw err
    }

    console.log('stdout', stdout)
    console.log('stderr', err)
})
```

Errors:

```
Error: Command failed: Taskkill /PID 7440 /T
ERROR: The process with PID 16320 (child process of PID 16876) could not be terminated.
Reason: The process cannot terminate itself.
ERROR: The process with PID 16876 (child process of PID 7440) could not be terminated.
Reason: One or more child processes of this process were still running.
ERROR: The process with PID 7440 (child process of PID 10880) could not be terminated.
Reason: One or more child processes of this process were still running.
```

Comment: `process.exit()`...?

Comment: I need also close cmd window, like pressing the "X" button

Comment: For that you need to open  cmd window with autoclose, doubt you can do that from inside

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with two alternatives:

If doesn't matter **kill all cmd's opened**.

```
  console.log("Closing all cmd opened..")
  exec('taskkill /IM cmd.exe')
```

**Kill the cmd where the script is running**. Set a CMD environment variable with an unique value, asign it to the title of the cmd, search the cmd with this title and kill it through his PID.

```
console.log("Searching current cmd...")
// set unique env variable
exec('set uniqueTitle=%time%%random%');
// set title cmd with env variable
exec('title=%uniqueTitle%')
exec('for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %A in (\'tasklist -v ^| findstr /i "%uniqueTitle%"\') do (taskkill /PID %A)', (err: string, stdout: string) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }

    console.log('stdout', stdout)
    console.log('stderr', err)
})
```

Full code:

```
console.log('This ts file must be terminate itself');

let asdef = process.pid;
let asdeff = process.ppid;

const { exec } = require('child_process')

//console.log("Closing all cmd opened..")
//exec('taskkill /IM cmd.exe')

 console.log("Searching current cmd...")
// set unique env variable
exec('set uniqueTitle=%time%%random%');
// set title cmd with env variable
exec('title=%uniqueTitle%')
exec('for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %A in (\'tasklist -v ^| findstr /i "%uniqueTitle%"\') do (taskkill /PID %A)', (err: string, stdout: string) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }

    console.log('stdout', stdout)
    console.log('stderr', err)
})
```

Comment: Not working for me, i need the kill the cmd where the script is running

Comment: The second option kills the cmd where the script is running. I've edited the answer adding the script with the solution.

Comment: Still same. This code does not close cmd window.

Comment: @MehmetAslan Which version of Windows are you using? If you run the script with the full code in my answer, Is it show any errors? The part of your code that close the script showing the Error: Command failed: Taskkill /PID 7440 /T... is not neccessary for closing the cmd window.

Comment: I'm using windows 10, no it doesn't give any errors but it doesn't close the CMD window either. I am sharing the code and screenshot of how it works, please review it. I need to close the CMD window where the code is running. Here is the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/n0SUuO9DcVzM

Comment: @MehmetAslan I've just edit the answer. Check it and tell me if it solves the problem

Comment: It works, thanks. But can i do same thing with pid?

Comment: The only way to close the current cmd it's search his PID first and then kill it with taskkill

Comment: I already did try this but not working.